# Only the last circle is shown in saved BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics

I want to render n circles in a `BufferedImage` but my problem is that only the last one is visible. Can you help me to find my failure? Perhaps it has something to do with the loops I'm using. Thanks in advance.

Scene.java

```
public class Scene {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private BufferedImage imageOfScene;
    private ArrayList<Geometry> geometries;
    private final String folderToSaveIn = "doc/";
    private final String fileName   = "a02.png";

    public Scene(int width,int height){
        this.geometries = new ArrayList<Geometry>();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.imageOfScene = new BufferedImage(
            this.width, this.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
        );
        System.out.println("The scene has a size of:"+width+"X"+height);
    }

    public void renderScene(){
        for (int x = 0; x != width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y != this.height; y++) {
                for (Geometry geometry: this.geometries){
                    if(geometry.isHit(x,y)){
                        this.imageOfScene.setRGB(x, y, geometry.getColor().getRGB());
                    }
                    else
                        this.imageOfScene.setRGB(x,y,giveColorForThisPixel(y));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int giveColorForThisPixel(int y){
        double y2 = (double) y;
        double t = y2/this.height;
        int value = (int) (t* 255);
        return new Color(0, 0, value).getRGB();
    }

    public void saveScene(){

        try {
            File outputfile = new File(this.folderToSaveIn +fileName);
            ImageIO.write(this.imageOfScene, "png", outputfile);
            System.out.println("Wrote image: " + fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void addGeometry(Geometry geometry){
        geometries.add(geometry);
    }


    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public ArrayList<Geometry> getGeometries() {
        return geometries;
    }
}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle extends Geometry {

    private final int radius;
    private final int centerX;

    private final int centerY;

    public Circle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius, Color color){
        super(color);
        this.radius = radius;
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isHit(int x,int y) {
        if( Math.pow( (x - this.centerX),2) +  Math.pow((y - this.centerY),2) < Math.pow(this.radius,2))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Circle{" +
                "radius=" + radius +
                ", centerX=" + centerX +
                ", centerY=" + centerY +
                ", color=" + getColor() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    static String   name    = "doc/a02.png";
    static int      width   = 480;
    static int      height  = 270;
    static int widthRatio = 16;
    static int heightRatio = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int numberOfCircles = 2;
        Random random = new Random();
        int ratioMultiplier = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(30,121);
        System.out.println(ratioMultiplier);
        //Scene scene = new Scene(width,height);
        Scene scene = new Scene(widthRatio*ratioMultiplier,heightRatio*ratioMultiplier);
        //ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++){
            int centerX = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,height+1);
            int centerY = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,width+1);
            int radius = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20,80);
            scene.addGeometry(new Circle(centerX,centerY,radius,getRandomColor()));
            System.out.println(scene.getGeometries());
        }

        scene.renderScene();
        scene.saveScene();
    }
    static Color getRandomColor(){
        return new Color(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,256),
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,256),
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0,256)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `renderScene()` method. Change to it:

```
   public void renderScene(){
        for (int x = 0; x != width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y != this.height; y++) {
                this.imageOfScene.setRGB(x, y, giveColorForThisPixel(y));
                for (Geometry geometry: this.geometries) {
                    if (geometry.isHit(x, y)) {
                        this.imageOfScene.setRGB(x, y, geometry.getColor().getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When your code execute `else this.imageOfScene.setRGB(x,y,giveColorForThisPixel(y));` inside `renderScene()` method, the last circle "erase" the previous circle.

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. And I think it makes more sense to only calculate the color for a pixel if it's not on an geometry instead rendering the background first and render the geometries after that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. At first it doesn't work but now it's working.